# tkinter in Pycharm (python version 3.8.6)

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.8

I'm using Pycharm on Windows 10.
Python version: 3.8.6

I've checked using the CMD if I have tkinter install `python -m tkinter`. It says I have version 8.6

Tried:

1. `import tkinter`.
   I get "No module named 'tkinter' "
2. `from tkinter import *`.
   I get "Unresolved reference 'tkinter'"
3. Installed future package but that didn't seem to change the errors.

Any suggestions on how to fix this issue?

Thank you!

Comment: That's an issue with pycharm's virtual environment, not with tkinter. Ask in a pycharm beginner's forum, for example pycharm.reddit.com

Answer (score -1):

You just verify in the project settings, sometimes Pycharm doesn't use the same interpreter.

Comment: What do you mean ? how can i verify.

Answer (score -1):

You can try "pip install tkinter" in cmd